# Organic Menus for every group wont show

Tags: routes, organic-groups

I've made a module to create organic groups and step by step content types inserting ,, at the end of the wizard I made a function to create og_menu for every group which get created fine.

but my problem is with showing the menu for each group!!

I tried to place the Single block ,, but nothing happened?

Am I missing something here?

any help would be appreciated

Thanx